# Converting PNG byte array to JPEG byte array in java

Tags: java, image, png, jpeg

I am not sure what I am exactly doing here so please give some advise and forgive the mistakes.

I have a image `byte[]` called `idCardImage` and I did the following to convert it to a String:

```
String s = new String(idCardImage);
```

And it prints out like this:

```
data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAEHUlEQVQ4TzWUW49VRRCFv6rq3ufMmTNn....
```

Did some search online and it seems this image is in a `png` format with base 64 encoded.

What I need to do is to convert it to a `jpeg` format and then store it in a new  byte array. Can you give some advise on how to do it with Java?

Comment: actually, that's a data uri, which happens to contain a base64-encoded png image.

Comment: http://www.mkyong.com/java/convert-png-to-jpeg-image-file-in-java/

Comment: @Pshemo I actually saw that link but I don't have any jpg file, I only have a byte array.

Comment: @MarcB I think you are right, please correct me if I am wrong, the png data is after `base64,`, correct?

Comment: yes. the `iVB...` stuff is the base64 data. no idea if java has a data uri parsing library (probably does), but if nothing else, you can simply use a string operation to extract the b64 data and then load that into a b64-decoder

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if that is most efficient way, but you could:

1) convert data from that string to bytes representing image, like:

```
String dataUrl = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABQAAAAUCAYAAACNiR0NAAAEHUlEQVQ4TzWUW49VRRCFv6rq3ufMmTNn...";
String header = "data:image/png;base64";

String encodedImage = dataUrl.substring(header.length()+1); //+1 to include comma 
byte[] imageData = Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedImage); //decode bytes
```

2) convert that bytes to `BufferedImage` holding PNG image

```
BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(imageData));
```

3) then based on http://www.mkyong.com/java/convert-png-to-jpeg-image-file-in-java/ you could create separate BufferedImage and fill it using JPG fromat

> ```
>  // create a blank, RGB, same width and height, and a white background
>  BufferedImage newBufferedImage = new BufferedImage(bufferedImage.getWidth(),
>         bufferedImage.getHeight(), BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
>  newBufferedImage.createGraphics().drawImage(bufferedImage, 0, 0, Color.WHITE, null);
> ```

***(this step can be simplified with `ImageIO.write(source, format, output)` as shown in [@Channa Jayamuni answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32851457/1393766))***

4) finally we can write these bytes to separate byte array with little help of ByteArrayOutputStream

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ImageIO.write(newBufferedImage, "jpg",baos);
byte[] byteArray = baos.toByteArray();
```

Comment: I am actually on Java 7 so I replaced the `Base64.getDecoder().decode(encodedImage);` with  `DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(encodedImage);` and it worked

Answer (score 5):

You can use `ImageIO` as interpreter to convert images in java. It allows to read image data, as same as write image data into specified format. It requires an `InputStream` to read image data. since you have a `byte[]` you can create a `ByteArrayInputStream` easily.

`ImageIO` requires an `OutputStream` to write byte data. And also `ByteArrayOutputStream` allows to extract it's `byte[]`. So you can write image bytes into a `ByteArrayOutputStream` and return its's bytes.

**Consider following example**

```
public byte[] pngBytesToJpgBytes(byte[] pngBytes) throws IOException {
    //create InputStream for ImageIO using png byte[]
    ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(pngBytes);
    //read png bytes as an image
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(bais);
    //create OutputStream to write prepaired jpg bytes
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //write image as jpg bytes
    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "JPG", baos);
    //convert OutputStream to a byte[]
    return baos.toByteArray();
}
```

Comment: `ImageIO.write(source, format, output)` makes things a lot easier +1